# What's this fuel line for?

Tags: fuel, fuel-systems, cessna, cessna-414

Cessna 414 ram conversion

[image]

What's this fuel line for that is coming to injector, other then the one from fuel distributor?

Answer (score 4):

It's a boost reference line which carries supercharged (Upper Deck) air to the injector for mixture atomization. Naturally aspirated engines don't need this as there is no positive pressure differential between intake manifold and the ambient atmosphere.